# How to access attribute of the main window

Tags: python

I am writing a program and I want for external function to access attribute of the main window.  It must be an external function, because it is provided by import method.  I have created a really small MWE to give an idea of the problem.  Here function `func` is supposed to print value of `MainWindow`'s `vari`.

```
class importedclass():
    def func(self):
        print(win.vari)

x=importedclass()

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.vari = 1
        x.func()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Just to make it clear: `importedclass` class is my fix-up class, I am not allowed to change anything in `MainWindow` class!

Comment: `func()` should have an argument so you can just pass self.vari, should it not?

Comment: No, the idea is that `func` gets `vari` itself

Comment: I am assuming that you wrote `importedclass`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Because each one needs an instance of the other, one of them needs to pass itself to the other. Check if this example solution fully addresses your problem.

```
# file 1

class External():
    def func(self, win):
        print(win.vari)


# file 2

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.vari = 1
        import External
        x = External()
        x.func(self)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I suggested this in the comments, and the OP said `No, the idea is that func gets vari itself`. I think this is a good solution, but it doesn't seem to fit with what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not solution to my problem.  The external class is actually fix-up and I am not allowed to change anything in MainWindow class.

Comment: As I stated in the answer, if the requirements are indeed that each one must know the **instance** of the other, any solution in which one doesn't pass its instance to the other will sound like miracle to me. But I hope someone comes up with something as I am now also curious if this is possible at all.